# R, extracting value from one attribute based on another attribute

Tags: r

I've run some analysis that outputs data in the following format:

```
> sft
   Power SFT.R.sq   slope truncated.R.sq mean.k. median.k. max.k.
1      1  0.35400  8.4300         0.7710  146.00    145.00  166.0
2      2  0.21900  2.2500         0.8960   83.30     82.80  107.0
3      3  0.17300  1.1600         0.9310   49.90     49.80   72.0
4      4  0.04100  0.3070         0.7360   31.60     31.20   50.3
5      5  0.00165 -0.0298         0.4610   21.30     21.00   37.3
6      6  0.05310 -0.1780        -0.1240   15.30     14.60   28.9
7      7  0.21300 -0.2610        -0.0113   11.60     10.90   24.0
8      8  0.63800 -0.5280         0.5560    9.27      8.18   22.3
9      9  0.82500 -0.6310         0.8110    7.69      6.14   21.2
10    10  0.85000 -0.7400         0.8100    6.59      4.97   20.3
11    11  0.82200 -0.8310         0.7710    5.77      3.95   19.6
12    12  0.81900 -0.8480         0.7680    5.16      3.27   19.0
13    13  0.73300 -0.8670         0.6660    4.67      2.80   18.4
14    14  0.65300 -0.9170         0.5840    4.28      2.39   17.9
15    15  0.70200 -0.9130         0.6440    3.97      2.22   17.4
```

What I want is to extract the Power that gave the highest (maximum) SFT.R.sq value.

Here is the table's attributes:

```
>str(sft)
List of 2
 $ powerEstimate: int NA
 $ fitIndices   :'data.frame':  15 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Power         : int [1:15] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ SFT.R.sq      : num [1:15] 0.35392 0.21883 0.17291 0.04098 0.00165 ...
  ..$ slope         : num [1:15] 8.4267 2.2461 1.158 0.307 -0.0298 ...
  ..$ truncated.R.sq: num [1:15] 0.771 0.896 0.931 0.736 0.461 ...
  ..$ mean.k.       : num [1:15] 145.8 83.3 49.9 31.6 21.3 ...
  ..$ median.k.     : num [1:15] 145.1 82.8 49.8 31.2 21 ...
  ..$ max.k.        : num [1:15] 165.6 107.1 72 50.3 37.3 ...
```

I can grab the two columns I need easily with:

```
sft$fitIndices$Power
sft$fitIndices$SFT.R.sq
```

But I can't get the actual power associated with the highest SFT.R.sq value:

```
>sft$fitIndices$Power[max(sft$fitIndices$SFT.R.sq)]
integer(0)
```

Examples of what I'm trying to do usually involve dataframes where you extract a value based on the value from another column - but it doesn't seem to work with attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `which.max` to return the position of `max` value for subsetting the 'Power'

```
sft$fitIndices$Power[which.max(sft$fitIndices$SFT.R.sq)]
```

---

Also, if we need to `slice` the row, extract the `data.frame` element and `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
pluck(sft, "fitIndices") %>%
     slice_max(n = 1, order_by = "SFT.R.sq")
```